# Google Chrome inside Docker container: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Dockerfile that installs Google Chrome and chromedriver

```
FROM python:3.9 AS base

ENV PATH "/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE True

FROM base as builder
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
COPY requirements requirements
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install -r requirements/common.txt

FROM base
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -qO /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

ENV DISPLAY=:1

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv
COPY . .

ARG PORT=5000
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 api:app
```

It always worked, until today I got the error:

> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Is some new release of chromedriver or google it self that broke?

What can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When DISPLAY is :0, you MUST add the option `headless`

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```